# How to display first element of list in fastapi pydantic model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have a user model from my database. Users could have a list of "recommended_profil", an other object in my database.
When a get endpoint is trigger on a user, I would like to display the first element of "recommended_profil", not the totality of the list.

See my models and schema below :

### sqlalchemy models

```py
class User_Wallet_Recommended(Timestamp,Base) : 
    __tablename__ = "users_wallet_recommended"

    id = Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=False)


    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="recommended_profil", foreign_keys=[user_id])

class User(Timestamp,Base) : 
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True),primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4)
    hashed_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    
    first_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)

    email = Column(EmailType, unique=True,index=True,nullable=False)
    recommended_profil = relationship("User_Wallet_Recommended", back_populates="owner")
```

### My schema :

```py
class User(UserBase):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    id: UUID
    ...
    recommended_profil : User_Wallet_Recommended_Out | None = None
```

Can't retrieve a single element of User_Wallet_Recommended_Out because I have a list instead...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `@field_validator`:

```
from uuid import uuid4, UUID
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, field_validator


class User_Wallet_Recommended_Out(BaseModel):
    id: UUID


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    pass


class User(UserBase):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

    id: UUID
    recommended_profil : User_Wallet_Recommended_Out | None = None

    @field_validator("recommended_profil", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def serialize_recomended_profil(cls, recomended_profil):
        if len(recomended_profil):
            return recomended_profil[0]
        else:
            return None

u = User.model_validate({"id": uuid4(), "recommended_profil": [{"id": uuid4()}, {"id": uuid4()}]})
print(u.model_dump())

u2 = User.model_validate({"id": uuid4(), "recommended_profil": []})
print(u2.model_dump())
```

Output:

```
{'id': UUID('f60af8b5-286c-4a05-bcc6-33ab52e1af4a'), 'recommended_profil': {'id': UUID('acadcbe5-205f-4579-b69f-da281182ff22')}}
{'id': UUID('c673b440-5e05-4d39-967e-4592b3105340'), 'recommended_profil': None}
```